# One Plus 1 - Logs out and immediately back in WiFi randomly

Tags: wi-fi, oneplus-one

The phone from my girlfriend is a OnePlus 1. About 4 to 5 times every hour, it disconnects and reconnect back to the Wifi. Sometimes the disconnect time lasts 3 minutes, sometimes 10 seconds, but it happens continuously. I have tried to find out why, but I could not find any answer.

What could I do to stop this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

I used to get these errors till a few weeks back myself,especially on a friend's wifi hotspot, and strangely enough,same problem was on friends' oneplus 2 and 3, and not even a stutter on other friend's nexus6p/iphone6/moto turbo.

Flashing a new rom helped a lot,currently running Mahdi rom, works pretty great and wifi stutters have reduced significantly(still,not zero, although barely once or twice per hour compared to the old 5-6 times back on stock), so if that's a possibility,go for it!
PS Worked on oneplus 2 and 3 as well, Custom Roms in, wifi disconnections out!